# Variable in the google document

Tags: google-docs

I have a large google document I'm working on. There is the same text there that used in many places. It is changed sometimes as the document evolves. I'd like to have some way to change it automatically. I declare a variable `some_variable` in some document metadata layer with the value of "text". Then everywhere this variable is inserted as `${some_variable}` it will be automatically replaced with "text". In this case I won't have to go over and do it manually. I believe this feature is available in MS-Word. Is it possible to do the same in google-docs.

I've tried [Doc Variables](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/doc_variables/232821636920) plug-in. However, it seem to be able to only replace variables with values once.

Answer (score 0):

for Doc Variables you can use a template and create copies.  That is how I use it for the same doc multiple times.  But, no, it does not retain a replaced variable after it was processed.